# Iterations with Table?

Tags: list-manipulation

Is the following code efficient? Has it any advantages?

```
s[0] = Sqrt[2]; 
Table[s[t + 1] = s[t]^2, {t, 0, 4}]
```

{2, 4, 16, 256, 65536}

Should be efficient in the following case?

```
s[0] = Sqrt[2];
Table[s[t + 1] = (1 + t)*s[t]^2, {t, 0, 4}]
```

{2, 8, 192, 147456, 108716359680}

How could a "stopping rule" alla `NestWhileList` be implemented?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dennis! The only accepted language here is English. If you need help translating your questions or answers, other users can help you. Just ask for help in chat!. Suerte, causa!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not formulated in English.

Comment: @m_goldberg Voted to close too. Then I thought again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need iterations to accomplish what you are looking for.

For example:

```
s[0]=Sqrt[2];
s[t_] := s[t] = s[t - 1]^2  (* Use memoization *)
Map[s, Range[1,5] ]
(* {2, 4, 16, 256, 65536} *)
```

and in the second case:

```
ss[0] = Sqrt[2];
ss[t_] := ss[t] = t ss[t - 1]^2
Map[ss, Range[1,5] ]
(* {2, 8, 192, 147456, 108716359680} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If efficiency is important and you are going to generate more and more elements of your series then you might consider using RSolve to find an expression for all terms.

```
RSolve[{s[t + 1] == s[t]^2, s[0] == Sqrt[2]}, s[t], t]
```

and

```
RSolve[{s[t + 1] == (1 + t)*s[t]^2, s[0] == Sqrt[2]}, s[t], t]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate some alternatives:

```
f[n_] := Nest[#^2 &, 2, n]
fl[n_] := NestList[#^2 &, 2, n]
```

Then

```
Table[f[j], {j, 0, 4}]
f /@ Range[0, 4]
fl[4]
```

all yield: {2, 4, 16, 256, 65536}